# A class from a nested class outside with dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

How can I put a class from a nested class outside in c++? I would like to do it with dynamic allocation.

Here is the code:

```
class LZWBinTree{
   public: 
      LZWBinTree():tree (&root){}    

      ~LZWBinTree(){   
         free(root.oneChild());     
         free(root.zeroChild());     
      }

      void operator<< (char b){     
         if (b=='0'){    
            if (!tree->zeroChild()){
               Node *uj=new Node('0');   
               tree->newZeroChild(uj);    
               tree=&root;     
            }
            else
               tree=tree->zeroChild();  
         }
         else{ 
            if (!tree->oneChild()){  
               Node *new=new Node('1');   
               tree->newOneChild(new);   
               tree=&root;     
            }
            else
               tree=tree->oneChild();  
         }
      }

      void write(void){  
         depth=0;  
         write(&root, std::cout);
      }

      int getDepth(void);        
      double getAverage(void);       
      double getDispersion(void);

      friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, LZWBinTree &bf){
         bf.write(os);
         return os;
      }

      void write(std::ostream &os){
         depth=0;
         write(&root, os);
      }
   private:
      class Node{ 
         public:
            Node(char b='/'):letter(b), leftZero(0), rightOne(0){};
            ~Node(){};
            Node *zeroChild() const{
               return leftZero;
            }
            Node *oneChild() const{ 
               return rightOne;
            }
            void newZeroChild(Node *gy){
               leftZero=gy;
            }
            void newOneChild(Node *gy){ 
               rightOne=gy;
            }
            char getLetter() const{
               return letter;
            }

         private: 
            char letter; 
            Node *leftZero;
            Node *rightOne;
            Node(const Node &); 
            Node &operator= (const Node &); 
      }; 
      Node *tree;
      int depth, averagesum, averagepiece;    
      double dispersionsum;      
      LZWBinTree (const LZWBinTree&);  
      LZWBinTree& operator= (const LZWBinTree&);    

      void write(Node *element, std::ostream & os){    
         if(element!=NULL){  
            ++depth;
            write(element->oneChild(), os);
            for(int i = 0; i<depth; ++i)
               os << "---";
            os << element->getLetter() << "(" << depth-1 << ")" <<  std::endl;
            write(element->zeroChild(), os);
            --depth;
         }
      }

      void free(Node *element){
         if(element!=NULL){ 
            free(element->oneChild());     
            free(element->zeroChild());    
            delete element;  
         }
      }

   protected:  
      Node root;
      int maxDepth;   
      double average, dispersion;

      void rdepth(Node *element);
      void raverage(Node *element);
      void rdispersion(Node *element);

};
```

I would like the Node class to be outside the LZWBinTree class. Is it enough to just copy and paste it or how can I use dynamic allocation?

Comment: _"I would like the Node class to be outside the `LZWBinTree` class."_ Then just put the declaration outside of that class. This has nothing to do with dynamic allocation in 1st place. I don't get what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the **Node** class from outside because it is declared **private** inside your **LZWBinTree** class. If you want to make it accessible, change the access modifier. From:

```
private:
    class Node{ ...
```

To:

```
public:
    class Node{ ...
```

Once you do that, you can create instances of your node class by accessing it through the class it is in, as follows:

```
LZWBinTree::Node n;
```

I'm not quite sure how dynamic allocation can help you in this case.

Comment: That's not necessarily better, because he might want to keep the related classes coupled together. Of course, you are right in that it is an acceptable solution.

Comment: true, though from the OP's wording I understand that he wants to put the `Node` class outside `LZWBinTree`